# Files uploaded via FTP aren't showing changes on Squarespace Developer Mode

Tags: ftp, less, config, squarespace

My squarespace site is in developer mode. I download files, like the `.region`, `.less`, and `.conf` files and edit them locally. I upload these files and expect to see a change on the squarespace site.

Up until yesterday this was working, then I made a mistake in one of the `LESS` files and got an error about incorrectly parsed JSON in the `.conf` file where the `LESS` file was included. I got a whole ton of errors from this, and have since then fixed both the `LESS` file and the `.conf` file.

However, the issue is that my squarespace site is now not registering that any changes have been uploaded, despite the fact that my FTP files are successfully being uploaded and downloaded from the FTP server.

I have also not seen any updates to my Git on the developer mode tab since this error was registered.

My question is how to fix this, and how to start seeing edits done locally to region, etc, files again.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to turn off the developer mode and then turn it on back.

Comment: That's not a solution - that is throwing everything away and starting over.